# ng-class based on variable value

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a variable with 4 possible values and i want to add a class for the first 3 variables and another for first 2 variables, also the requirement will some time change to one class for two possible value and another for other value

so if i give

```
<span ng-class="{'yes' : provisioned=='active',
    'yes': provisioned=='cannot_delete_edit',
    'no': provisioned=='cannot_delete_edit_upload',
    'no': provisioned=='inactive'}" class="flag">
</span>
```

it is not working how can i solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have each class listed only once:

```
<span ng-class="{'yes': provisioned=='active' || provisioned == 'cannot_delete_edit', 'no': provisioned=='cannot_delete_edit_upload' || provisioned=='inactive', 'flag': true}"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your span has only two options, you can use this instead:

```
<span ng-class="(provisioned=='active' || provisioned == 'cannot_delete_edit') ?
                'yes' : 'no'">...</span>
```

But this still leaves hard-coded values in the HTML.  Instead, I would recommend leaving the data in the controller:

```
$scope.provisioned = (provisioned=='active' || provisioned == 'cannot_delete_edit');
```

and then using

```
<span ng-class="provisioned ? 'yes' : 'no'">...</span>
```